# Getting Error in java while Compiling or Running

Tags: java, runtime-error

i am new to java and i've downloaded a pdf document from wikibooks, and while trying to run a program i am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Distance.main(Distance.java:7)
```

This is the code i am trying to run:

```
public class Distance
{
    private java.awt.Point point0, point1;
    public Distance(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
    {
        point0 = new java.awt.Point(x0, y0);
        point1 = new java.awt.Point(x1, y1);
    }

    public void printDistance()
    {
        System.out.println("Distance between " + point0 + " and " + point1
            + " is " + point0.distance(point1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Distance dist = new Distance(
        intValue(args[0]), intValue(args[1]),
        intValue(args[2]), intValue(args[3]));
        dist.printDistance();
    }

    private static int intValue(String data)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your input and output?

Comment: the program is not even compiling it just shows an error and that's it..nothing else..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not provide parameters to command-line java invocation or in your IDE configuration.

It seems it needs four integer parameters, as in:

```
java Distance 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Run- > Run Configurations-> (Find your configuration - most likely Java Application called Distance) -> Arguments Tab -> Program arguments -> Run.

Comment: can you tell me what is this and why is it used, please if you have time?

Comment: Well, it seems your program calculates the Euclidean distance between two points on a 2D plane. It could either generate those points randomly, or it can use the user's input. In this case, it is the latter.

Comment: then do i have to go all this process while trying to run this "everytime"?

Comment: Once you add it to the configuration once, it is saved, and it will use the same input until you change it.

Comment: can i ask u a last question.. i've made some other beginner programs and those also needed some parameters from the user and it just worked like normal application like it asked the parameters after running. then why is this one like this?

Comment: You see `main`'s signature has a format parameter called `args`? If the application ever needs input from the user, it will use the `args` array in the main function. See how your `main` uses `args` with this statement `intValue(args[0])`? Your other programs might not ask for input this way. They can ask you directly from the command line, and it will ask you to type something when the programs is ready to receive input. It all depends on the original coder and their preference.

Comment: i've entered the parameters in Program Variables in this manner "1, 2, 3, 4" and it's showing following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Distance.intValue(Distance.java:23)
 at Distance.main(Distance.java:17)

Comment: got it removed the commas and it worked, Thank You Very very very much for your help and support....

Comment: You have to separate the arguments with spaces, always. Thanks.